# addEventListener does not work on click event…

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener

I want to handle a click event with the `id="ticker"` with `addEventListener`. 
onclick works.

```
document.getElementById("ticker").onclick = function() {
timeChange(5);
}
```

**But I don't understand, why it does not work with** `addEventListener`

This is what I wrote:

```
document.getElementById("ticker").addEventListener("click", timeChange, false);
```

This ist the function `timeChange` I want to call:

```
const display = document.getElementById("counter");
function timeChange(seconds) {
  let seconds = 5;
  display.innerText = seconds; // seconds + 1; ??
  // page.secondChild.nodeValue = seconds;
  seconds -= 1;
  if (seconds > -1) {
    setTimeout(timeChange, 1000, seconds);
  }
}
```

In related problems I read something about closures. But I can't see an issue in "my" `addEventListener` related to the closure topic.

This is the HTML:

But before this is the button     `<button id="ticker">` which triggers the event. (At the end of the HTML)

```
<body>
    <div id="page">
      <div id="counter">5</div>
      <div id="btn"><button id="ticker">Start Pomodoro</button></div>
    </div>
    <div id="otput">
      <p>This is your</p>
      <p id="sessions"></p>
      <p>session</p>
    </div>

    <div id="page1">
      <div id="counter1">5</div>
      <div id="btn1"><button id="ticker">Start Pomodoro</button></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Define "does not work". Is there an error?

Comment: Yes, I did not checked that. It was "seconds already defined". But I did not solve it either. Thanks for this reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since you are not passing an argument to `timeChange`, the function shouldn't have `seconds` declared as one.

Next, you need to declare your `seconds` variable outside of the callback function so that it can retain its value after being changed by that function.

Lastly, you have two buttons with the same `id`. `id`s must be unique within a document.

```js
document.getElementById("ticker").addEventListener("click", timeChange);
let display = document.getElementById("counter");

let seconds = 5;
function timeChange() {
  display.textContent = seconds;
  seconds -= 1;
  if (seconds > -1) {
    setTimeout(timeChange, 1000, seconds);
  }
}
```

```html
    <div id="page">
      <div id="counter">5</div>
      <div id="btn"><button id="ticker">Start Pomodoro</button></div>
    </div>
```

If you did want to pass an argument to `timeChange`, then you'd have to wrap your callback reference in another function that will actually become the callback.

```js
// Here, the callback is the anonymous function
document.getElementById("ticker").addEventListener("click", function() {   
  timeChange(5); // which will then invoke the actual function with an argument
});

let display = document.getElementById("counter");

let seconds = null;
function timeChange(sec) {
  seconds = sec; // Need to update the higher scoped variable 
  display.textContent = seconds;
  seconds -= 1;
  if (seconds > -1) {
    setTimeout(timeChange, 1000, seconds);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
      <div id="counter">5</div>
      <div id="btn"><button id="ticker">Start Pomodoro</button></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Oops. I marked it as solved. Thank you for your help. But as I wanted to upvote, it makes an down vote.

Comment: @S.H If you've down voted and want to retract it, click the down vote button a second time.

Comment: I did. Got this: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."